# suma de celdas de jtable

Tags: java

hola amigos veran necesito ayuda es que tengo una tabla principal que contiene un for entonces quisiera hacer una suma de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DefaultTableModel temp1 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    Object nuevo1[]= {"","","","",""};
    temp1.addRow(nuevo1);
    //suben
    jTable2.setValueAt(en,j,0);
    //bajan
    jTable2.setValueAt(numero, j, 1);
    //sobrantes
    jTable2.setValueAt(sobrantes, j, 2);

    System.out.println(jTable2.getValueAt(j, 2).toString());
```

Comment: gracias por preguntar. Tu pregunta me parece un poco confusa. Cuál es el error que intentas resolver? Exactamente en qué líneas del código que compartes te aparece el error? Cuál es el mensaje de error completo que obtienes?

Comment: bueno realmente solo capturo las filas y la columna es decir fila 1 y el dato esta en la columna 2 pero necesito sumar este con la siguiente fila justamente con el datos de la primera columna pero nose como hacerlo

Comment: un for no te funcionaría? ya lo intentaste?

Comment: realmente contiene el codigo un for pero esta mas atras de esta parte del codigo pero lo que haces es sumar ciertas columnas y esta tabla es la que se imprime mediante esta, pero no tengo idea de como hacer esas sumas como se ve en la imagen

Comment: Creo que un for bidimensional te puede funcionar. Revisa el siguiente link: http://lineadecodigo.com/java/sumar-matrices-en-java/

Comment: de acuerdo gracias me pondre a ver ese ejemplo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a tener una columna que es resultado de una fórmula de otras celdas del mismo renglón, quizás no convenga tener físicamente esa columna sino que retornes el valor dada la fórmula.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class MiModelo extends DefaultTableModel {

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int fila, int columna) {
    if (columna != 2) { // si no es la columna de sobrantes retornamos lo que contenga la celda
        return super.getValueAt(fila, columna);
    }
    //aquí llegamos cuando tengamos que retornar el valor del sobrante y lo calulculamos
    int sobrante = (int)getValueAt(fila, 0) - (int)getValueAt(fila, 1);
    return sobrante;
}
}
```

Nota: los valores de las columnas 0 y 1 deberán ser enteros. De lo contrario requerirás hacer conversión.

Si pudieras mostrar más código podría ver si hubiera mejores opciones para implementar lo que requieres.